# Job-seeker visa or work permit visa for a low-paying job

Tags: working-visas, germany, resident-permit, job-hunting

I already have a job in a German company, but the salary is lower than the blue card limits. I know that there is a work permit visa, which does not have salary limits. However, I am trying for another job with a better salary. I just completed my Master's program from a German University and hence, I am also eligible for applying for an 18-month job-seeker visa. I need clarifications for the following questions:

1. I would like to know which would be the better option to go if I would soon change my job? A job-seeker visa or a work permit visa.
2. For a job-seeker visa, is it possible to show my current job contract as financial proof or will I be asked to apply for a work permit visa as I have a contract already?
3. In case of a work permit visa, can I change my job any time I want? Is there any extra procedure that I need to carry out when I change jobs?
4. In the long run for getting a permanent residence permit, which of these two options would be better to take?
5. If I have a work permit visa, can I still apply for a blue card if I meet the salary requirements later?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: please split up your question into multiple parts, as it stands now it is a bit too broad to answer easily

Answer (score 1):

Just to help others, in case they are in similar situation.

**For question 3**: Yes, one can change job whenever he/she wants. However, if you have been in your for two years with your current permit, you need not get permission from the immigration office for changing your job. However, if you would like to change your job within two years, you need to go to the immigration office for getting clearance and to apply for a new residence title as the old permit is entitled only to your old job. In this case, it would be wise not to leave your previous job till you get everything sought out from the immigration office with your new job.

**For question 5**: Yes, you can. But the time that you need to collect for your settlement permit might start again.